# Splitting string up by period

Tags: java

Hello I have the following string I'm trying to split up for the hibernate createAlias and query restrictions.

I need to split the string in to three parts.

**employeeProfile.userProfile.shortname**

```
1. employeeProfile.userProfile
2. userProfile
3. userProfile.shortName
```

I'd also like it to be dynamic to do a different length string.

**employeeProfile.userProfile.anotherClass.shortname**

```
1. employeeProfile.userProfile.anotherClass
2. userProfile.anotherClass
3. anotherClass.shortName
```

I was able to get most of it to work with the exception of number three using the following code.

```
public void hasAlias(Criteria t, final Map<String, Object> map) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        if (key != null && key.contains(".")) {
            key = key.substring(0, key.lastIndexOf("."));
            String value = key.contains(".") ? key.substring(key.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, key.length()) : key;
            t.createAlias(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone help me to get number 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29). For example, you could do something like the following:

```
String[] tmp="foo.bar".split(".");
```

Once you have it in this form you can do whatever you need to with it.

Answer (score 1):

> employeeProfile.userProfile.shortname
>
> 1. employeeProfile.userProfile
> 2. userProfile
> 3. userProfile.shortName

Say we have this:

```
int index1 = str.indexOf(".");
int index2 = str.lastIndexOf(".");
```

Then this works (module + 1's here and there):

1. `substring(0, index2);`
2. `substring(index1, index2);`
3. `substring(index1);`

Comment: where are you getting index in number 3 ?

Comment: should have been `index1`. Corrected.

Comment: @George This will NOT work for the second example. Number 3 will be incorrect.

Comment: True. That got added after I answered... I also don't understand the logic of second example

Comment: @Summerbulb you are correct, it seemed to work in a quick test, but when I implemented it, it didn't work. I forgot to adjust the answer.

Answer (score 1):

To get number 3 you can use a regular expression. A regular expression that takes the last two item will be:

```
[a-zA-z]+\.[a-zA-z]+$
```

Get number 3 by using the following code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-z]+\\.[a-zA-z]+$");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher("employeeProfile.userProfile.anotherClass.shortname");

if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

This will print:

```
anotherClass.shortname
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have better luck with Java's StringTokenizer: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

You could set it up like this:

```
String myString = "employeeProfile.userProfile.shortname";
String myDelimiter = ".";
StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(myString,myDelimiter);
```

From this, you should be able to get what you need and play with the tokens.